# Get auto id of a new typed datarow

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

When inserting a new record using `table.newTableRow`, is it possible to get the `autoId`?

Here is my code:

```
Dim famtbl As New DataSet1.FamiliesDataTable
Dim newFam = famtbl.NewFamiliesRow

With newFam
    .Address = txt_Address.Text
    .City = txt_City.Text
    .State = txt_State.Text
    .Zip = txt_Zip.Text
    .Country = txt_Country.Text
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you will not know the ID until it is committed to the DB.

Comment: is possible to get the auto id once it is committed?

Comment: Yes, update the dataset accordingly and the ID should be set.

Comment: Updating didn't help. Get auto id of -1